# Trouble converting excel 2010 UI sort to VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am automating a process that utilizes Excel VBA 2010 to take two spreadsheets, combine them, sort them, delete duplicate data, and a bunch of other things.  I am vague because those all work and not pertinent to this thread.

The last task I am struggling with is converting the UI sort (see attached picture) into VBA code.

In all honest, I am at a loss, here is hte code I have started using, but feel it is not enough.  If this task I wish ot automate even possible in VBA?

```
Private Sub score_sort()
Dim sort_rng As Range
Dim aCell As Range
Dim bCell As Range
counter = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
column_letter = Replace(Cells(1, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Address(False, False), "1", "")
rng = ""
rng = "A1:" + column_letter + CStr(counter)
Set sort_rng = Range(rng)
Set aCell = Range("F2")
Set bCell = Range("H2")
sort_rng.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

End Sub

To match the picture to ranges "Final Score" = F1 and "Potential Score" = H1

Thanks

[image: Worksheet sort using excel 2010 UI]

Comment: Is this something you could use the macro recorder for?  I'm not sure if that catches the sort box, but if so, this seems like an ideal use of it.

Comment: @thunderblaster: It does, and that's exactly the way to do it.

Comment: @thunderblaster, thanks for that.  I recorded the marco to do what I needed, but was having trouble calling it, so I just took the code, and moved it to a sub in my VBA code and it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @thunderblaster for the suggestion of capturing this using a macro.  I am very particular about my code, so I used the code provided by the macro recorder to build the sub in my VBA code.  I am sharing it with the community to be used or expanded upon.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(f_rng), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    0, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(f_rng), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    200, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(f_rng), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    255, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(p_rng), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    0, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(p_rng), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    200, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(p_rng), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    255, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(f_rng), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, _
    255, 0)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:Y30")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```